# How to create an Audio Player with volume control using JACO mp3 player in core java?

Tags: java

I have created an audio player using JACO MP3 player.I'm not able to set the volume for playing audio file.How can I do it?

Comment: Seems you can't with that jar, you could still mess with the sound devices itself, but you probably find a better api to play music...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Can you please suggest me any other jar with volume control?

Comment: Look at the source code.  There is a method called `setVolume` ....

Comment: I'm using Jaco mp3 player jar. In that I didn't find setVolume method.

Comment: I saw it in the source code: https://sourceforge.net/p/jacomp3player/code/HEAD/tree/JACo%20MP3%20Player/src/jaco/mp3/player_v2/MP3Player.java